# Android generating background along moving sprite

Tags: android, image, background

My question is how the logic works for a games background that keeps generating with objects on it, For example a pig is rolling down a hill, on this hill is trees and corn, before the pig reaches the end of the screen the map has to add more background so he dosnt roll over the end of the world ^^

If I'm unclear let me know and Ill try to explain more.